# Show a pdf from http get call in a UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, alamofire, ios10

I am using swift 3, xcode 8 and Alamofire for a ios10 app. I'm working against a API and one service gives you the posibilty to get files. The file could be a image or pdf. It works fine to make the call and get a image and show it in a UIImageView (and in a CollectionView) but I cant show the pdf. If I copy a pdf inside to the Assets (folder in the app) it's visible in the UIImageView. Is it possible to get a pdf throw http and show it in a UIImageView and if so, any suggestions?

Comment: can you get the pdf as an image from the server, or can it only be retrieved as a pdf?

Comment: Only retrieved as a pdf, thats the problem. Works fine with with images.

Comment: darn. I was going to suggest retrieving them as images and then converting them to pdf.

Comment: could you include your code for the alamofire request plus the url? unless the api and url are private/need authorization.

Comment: If you have pdf in response then better you can use UIDocumentInteractionController to preview your pdf document. if it is a image means you can go with imageView. If you want let me provide swift code for previewing your pdf document.

Comment: Yes,pls. I would like to see code for previewing pdf.